# Необходимо отследить закрытие окна javascript

Tags: javascript

```
newwin=window.open(url,'name',params);
```

Для newwin необходимо вызвать функцию при его закрытии.

```
newwin.onclose = qwe;

function qwe() {
    alert('123asdas');
}
```

Такой метод не сработал, есть какие-нибудь другие способы?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У открытого окна есть такое свойство closed, его нужно проверять по таймеру и если она станет равно true то запустить вашу функцию.

Например так:

```
/**
* wind - переменная содержащая идентификатор открытого окна
* cb - кэллбек функция вызываемая при закрытии окна
**/
      var popupMonitor = function(wind, cb) {
          vavr a = true;
            try {
              if( wind.closed ) {
                a = false;
                cb && cb();
              } 
            } catch(e) {}

          if( a ) {
            window.setTimeout(function(){
              popupMonitor(wind, cb)
            }, 1000);
          } 
        };
```

Нужно обратить внимание на то, что домен открываемого окна должен совпадать с доменом окна откуда открывается окно.

Comment: Спасибо, помогло!